# how many pints cooked cabbage from 3 pounds raw?

Tags: freezing, cabbage

How many pints of cooked cabbage should I be able to get out of 2 cabbage heads (about 3 pounds each) ? I am wanting to cook and freeze the cabbage.

Comment: @Ecnerwal : not a duplicate, as extra moisture is expelled during the fermentation.

Comment: Why would you want to measure cooked cabbage in *pints*? A weight measure sounds more useful.

Comment: @JanDoggen we are fighting an uphill battle here: That's almost a whole continent that was culinarily trained by settlers women who had no scales, just some sort of cups. I doubt that we'll see that change in our lifetime.

Comment: @JanDoggen : likely because they're putting it into hard-sided containers, which are measured by volume not by weight.  Eg, deli containers, tupperware, gladware, etc.  Even freezer bags are measured in cups, pints & gallons.

Comment: @Joe **this exact question is answered** as part of the accepted answer, in addition to the sauerkraut answer.

Comment: @Ecnerwal : as I've said at least a dozen times before -- I don't care if they have the same answer, it's a different question.  Would we claim that questions are a duplicate just because the answer for all of them is 'no' ?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how much you cook the cabbage.

Less cooking not only means that it's firmer and it won't compact as easily, but that the majority of the water is still in the cabbage, adding volume.

The longer that you cook the cabbage, the more that the cell walls break down, moisture is expelled, and that moisture evaporates.  (but evaporation is also a function of the surface area of the pan/pot it's being cooked in)

...

I've personally never paid attention to the volume of cooked cabbage, but I have for cabbage that's been salted, let sit and drained to make cole slaw ... and that's closer to 1.5 to 2 pints per 3 lb cabbage.  (but again, it depends how much force you use to pack it ... and how much you cut out when removing the core).

I'll try to remember to get a measurement when I make a ~10lb batch of cole slaw for a gathering in two weeks.